# Unexpected behavior of global variable in use with multiprocessing module

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, global-variables

I was rewriting my application. While I wanted to use a global variable to pass some information to a function. I noticed that the value of the global variable did not change after I change it. Additionally, I noticed that behaviors differ depending on the syntax of "pool.map_async". Below is a code that reproduces this error.

The first example is when a job does not have any parameter but I pass "job()" to "=func" like this "func=job()" (passing just a "job" looks like a process is not being executed)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

x = None

def job():
    print(x,"Inside Job")

def main():
    global x
    x = 10
    pool = Pool(1)
    li = [0]
    pool.map_async(iterable=li,func=job())
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print("End of main")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(x,"Before")
    main()
    print(x,"After")
```

**Console output**

```
None Before
10 Inside Job
End of main
10 After
```

The output is as expected, value x inside job is correct.

Now if let function job to take any argument like below

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

x = None

def job(z):
    print(z)
    print(x,"Inside Job")

def main():
    global x
    x = 10
    pool = Pool(1)
    li = [0]
    pool.map_async(iterable=li,func=job)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print("End of main")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(x,"Before")
    main()
    print(x,"After")
```

**Console output**

```
None Before
0
None Inside Job
End of main
10 After
```

The output shows that changing the value of x was not noticed.

Can somebody explain why using of "global" does not work when function "job"  takes an argument?

I'm on python 3.7.0

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is Just Wrong. The `job` function must accept an argument.

Here is where things headed south in that example:

```
    pool.map_async(iterable=li, func=job())
```

You wanted:

```
    pool.map_async(iterable=li, func=job)
```

instead.

The return value from your function is `None`,
so you wound up synchronously executing `job()` in the context of `main`,
and then passing the resulting `None` to `map_async`.
The `global` statement in `main` affected the lookup of `x`.

The second example looks much better. It correctly displays `0`.

Rather than attempting to store values using `global`,
you would be happier if you stored such values in an object
and passed the object to `job` as an argument. For example:

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

points = [Point(3, 4), Point(5, 6)]
pool.map_async(iterable=points, func=job)
```

The multiprocessing documentation points to the [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) docs.
Together with the fact that only a single iterable may be supplied,
their advice boils down to:

> *function* must take [one] argument

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Is there any way to make x not to be None inside Job in my second example?